# excel decrease value by 1 if based on amount of columns with certain value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create an Excel file that decreases a value with 1 for each 'Yes' per row.

This is where I'm at:
[image: excel]

In the 'Vouchers left' column, the below formula is used:

```
=IF([@[12/07/2020]]="Yes";[@['# Vouchers]]-1)
```

But this only works for 1 column. If I select more columns it returns a #SPILL! error.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating another newColumn with the sum of all 'Yes', I used the following formula in this column.
`=SUM(IF((F2:Q2="Ja"); 1; 0))`

Then I replaced the formula in column 'Vouchers left' with `=B2-newColumn`.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use countif function like example below
Formula in column C: B1-countif(D1:G1,"Yes")
[Please click this for my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4t8e.png)

Comment: When I try this I'm getting an error: *You've entered too few arguments for this function.*

Comment: Working for me. what was the format you have in column B. If Text then you need to convert as number and apply the formula